# Endnote to bibtex issue

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

I have quite a few references in endnote and I want to convert them to BibTeX for a report I am writing in LyX.

Endnote has a BibTeX export feature and I now have a `.txt` file with all my references sitting on my desktop, but I am now at a loss as how to go about actually accessing it for my work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: What do you mean by 'access'? You can just open the file in a text editor to manipulate the entries. It should really be a .bib file, not a .txt file.

Comment: 'accessing it for my work' is indeed a little vague. You could use [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) for managing your BibTeX bibliography. [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) might also be an option for you as an alternative for Endnote. There is a Zotero plugin available, called [LyZ](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/lyz/), to insert citations to LyX directly from Zotero.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to use Jabref and to convert the files. I now have an up and running referencing manager.

Thanks for all the advice

Answer (score 1):

On the LyX menus, go to

```
Insert | List/TOC | BibTeX Bibliography
```

This will insert a "BibTeX Generated Bibliography".

You now need a *.bib file as a BibTeX database. If Evernote exports a proper BibTeX database as a *.txt file, you just need to rename it.

Selecting the context menu ("right clicking") over the "BibTeX Generated Bibliography" will open a dialogue box that will allow you to navigate to and select your *.bib BibTeX file.

Then, on the LyX menus again, you can just use

```
Insert | Citation
```

to cite any of the references from your BibTeX bibliography in your document.

Note the BibTeX "databases" (or files really) are quite easy to write and edit by hand.

Emacs has BibTeX mode

```
M-x bibtex-mode
```

if you need some clean up and additions to the Evernote export.